# How to Filter the variables with greater impact and perform glm regression on them

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, regression, data-science

I have 40 variables(categorical and numeric) and response variable is numeric, I want to perform glm regression in R only on the variables which have greater impact. I followed stepwise backward regression to achieve this and this selection seems to be costly and is taking ever to execute. Is there a better way of filtering impact variables other than this brute force approach(stepwise backward regression) to find a model that have only significant impact variables in R.

Comment: it's difficult to answer the question without more information, but I suggest you explore decision trees.

Comment: @user4970610 Using decision trees in R has limitations on number of levels to use for each factors(i.e.,52). But the factors in data has many more levels than that limit. Before feeding to regression I clustered the ones with more levels. 
After bit of exploring, seems like lasso is more effective for variable selection. Have to check about its performance on the data.